# Start and stop Python turtle with space bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to code a program that starts and stops a turtle by pressing the space bar. I got the code to start the turtle moving but it doesn't stop it when I press it again. It seems to just increase the speed. Here are my coding requirements and the code I typed up.

*Create a turtle program with three functions to control the turtle.  Create a function called turnLeft that turns the turtle 90 degrees left when the right arrow is pressed on the keyboard.  Create a function called turnRight that turns the turtle 90 degrees right when the right arrow is pressed.  Create a third function called move() that moves the turtle forward when the space bar is pressed, then stops the turtle when the spacebar is pressed a second time.*

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(400,500)
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Tess moves in space")
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
tess = turtle.Turtle()

def leftTurtle():
    tess.left(90)

def rightTurtle():
    tess.right(90)

state_num = 0

def advance_state_machine():
    global state_num
    if state_num == 0:       
        tess.penup()
        state_num = 1
    else:     
        tess.pendown()
        tess.forward(2)
        state_num = 0
    wn.ontimer(advance_state_machine, 25)

def exitWindow():
    wn.bye()

wn.onkey(advance_state_machine, "space")
wn.onkey(exitWindow, "q")
wn.onkey(leftTurtle, "Left")
wn.onkey(rightTurtle, "Right")

wn.listen()                      
wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it almost right except some tiny details to change. The global variable `state_num` decided in the `advance_state_machine()` function if the turtle should move or not. You got the proper logic for the turns, so why not apply the same logic for a move/pause ?

In your original code you were just switching each shown frame the global variable value from one state to another and with the SPACE key you started another instance of `advance_state_machine()` what made the turtle faster. The turtle got faster because with each SPACE a further loop implemented in `advance_state_machine()` was started to run in parallel to the existing one(s).

In the code below the function `movementControl()` changes the value of boolean `should_move` to the opposite one on SPACE and the `advance_state_machine()` evaluates `should_move` to let the turtle move or stop:

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(400,500)
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Tess moves in space")
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
tess = turtle.Turtle()

def leftTurtle():
    tess.left(90)

def rightTurtle():
    tess.right(90)

should_move = False

def movementControl():
    global should_move
    should_move = not should_move

def advance_state_machine():
    global should_move
    if should_move:       
        tess.pendown()
        tess.forward(2)
    else:     
        tess.penup()
    wn.ontimer(advance_state_machine, 25)

def exitWindow():
    wn.bye()

wn.onkey(movementControl, "space")
wn.onkey(exitWindow, "q")
wn.onkey(leftTurtle, "Left")
wn.onkey(rightTurtle, "Right")

wn.listen()                      
advance_state_machine()

wn.mainloop()
```

---

Wow!!! With `cdlane's` help we put here a really nice basic turtle example together.

Now I have modified HIS code a bit more towards a minimalistic version and got rid of the movementControl() function, too.

I personally don't like to use `from turtle import *` kind of import statements as they provide a huge number of available methods and variables which are "invisible" because you can't directly see where they come from,  BUT ... having ALL the code in a so short block isn't it worth it?

```
from turtle import *
setup(400, 500); title('Turtle moves in space')
bgcolor('lightgreen'); up()
def advance_state_machine():
    if isdown(): fd(2) 
    ontimer(advance_state_machine, 25)
onkey(lambda: (pd, pu)[isdown()](), 'space')
onkey(bye, 'q')
onkey(lambda: lt(90), 'Left')
onkey(lambda: rt(90), 'Right')
listen(); advance_state_machine(); done()
```

Comment: Also, renaming `state_num` to `should_draw` and making it a boolean makes the code read nicer, and the toggle becomes a one-liner: `should_draw = not should_draw`.

Comment: Thank you @Claudio and 9000 Y'all are awesome... I am VERY new to coding and python and this one was kicking my butt. This works perfect. One other question, is it possible to combined 'def movementControl():' and 'def advance_state_machine():' into one function?

Comment: @DavidWilliam: I don't think so, you need to call `advance_state_machine` and `movementControl` at very different times. (Also, let them be either both camelCase or both underscore_case, for the sake of consistency.)

Comment: Oh man, thanks @9000 good catch. I borrowed part of this code from another program and forgot to fix that. And yeah Clauido, I am still learning and trying to understand all the concepts of python (and I want to move onto others) and just trying to figure everything out. This site has been a huge help and I love programming so far, can't wait to learn more and become a better coder

Comment: A couple of code notes: the `global should_move` in ` advance_state_machine()` isn't needed; Why keep `exitWindow()` when you can just do `wn.onkey(wn.bye, "q")`.  Finally, you don't technically need `should_move` which I'll cover in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way the state variables `state_num` and/or `should_move` are used above can be seen as redundant with turtle's own `isdown()` predicate.  I've rewritten Claudio's solution accordingly but made it minimalist so the `isdown()` logic stands out:

```
from turtle import *

def movementControl():
    (pd, pu)[isdown()]()

def advance_state_machine():
    if isdown():
        fd(2)
    ontimer(advance_state_machine, 25)

setup(400, 500)
title('Turtle moves in space')
bgcolor('lightgreen')
up()

onkey(movementControl, 'space')
onkey(bye, 'q')
onkey(lambda: lt(90), 'Left')
onkey(lambda: rt(90), 'Right')

listen()

advance_state_machine()

done()
```