# "Stop" Button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to have a turtle animation start with a button and stop with a button. It's very easy to start with a button but I can't seem to be able to figure out a stop button? Here's my code so far:

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk
def start():
    t.forward(100)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(100)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(100)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(100)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(100)

def stop():
    t.stop

def clear():
    canvas.delete("all")

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()

t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)

tk.Button(text = "Start", command = start).pack(side = tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(text = "Stop", command = stop).pack(side = tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(text = "Clear", command = clear).pack(side = tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Also the clear button works but afterwards the start button doesn't work anymore. If someone can help me with that as well.

Thank you to @Mike - SMT for helping me with this code. Here's the edited and fully functioning code:

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk


def start(turtle_object, draw_path):
    global tracker, start_ndex, end_ndex, started
    tracker = False
    if started == False:
        started = True
        for i in range(start_ndex, end_ndex):
            if tracker == False and i <= end_ndex:
                pth = draw_path[i]
                if pth[0] == "f":
                    turtle_object.forward(pth[1])
                elif pth[0] == "r":
                    turtle_object.right(pth[1])
                elif pth[0] == "l":
                    turtle_object.left(pth[1])
                start_ndex += 1


running = True

def stop():
    global tracker, started
    tracker = True
    started = False

def clear():
    global t, tracker, started, start_ndex
    t.reset()
    start_ndex = 0
    started = False
    t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)


root = tk.Tk()
tracker = False
start_ndex = 0
started = False # added this tracking variable to prevent issues with     spamming the start button.

draw_path = [["f", 100], ["r", 90], ["f", 100], ["l", 90], ["f", 100], ["r", 90], ["f", 100], ["r", 90], ["f", 100]]


end_ndex = len(draw_path)

canvas = tk.Canvas(width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()

t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
tk.Button(text = "Start", command = lambda: start(t, draw_path)).pack(side = tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(text = "Stop", command = stop).pack(side = tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(text = "Clear", command = clear).pack(side = tk.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do You Make Python Turtle Stop Moving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619994/how-do-you-make-python-turtle-stop-moving)

Comment: There are a few post on how to stop the turtle. These post: [How to stop the python turtle from drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483288/how-to-stop-the-python-turtle-from-drawing), [Start and stop Python turtle with space bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591581/start-and-stop-python-turtle-with-space-bar), [How Do You Make Python Turtle Stop Moving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619994/how-do-you-make-python-turtle-stop-moving).

Comment: None of those resolve my problem.

Comment: They are the same question. You are not able to stop in between drawing because any even you would use to stop cant run until the function has ended. You will need to break up the drawing into sections and check a tracking variable.

Comment: So I can't stop the animation with a button? I need to have a start and stop button for my project :/ welp

Comment: You cannot simply stop mid line draw. But you can break it up so it stops after the current direction stops drawing. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot stop each draw statement unless you provide a checker in between each line drawn.

The below code is just a rough mock up of how you could make something to check for a tracking variable used to tell it to no longer draw new lines.

The closest thing you can do to being able to stop drawing is something like this:

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk

def start():
    global tracker
    tracker = False
    if tracker == False:
        t.forward(100)
    if tracker == False:
        t.right(90)
    if tracker == False:
        t.forward(100)
    if tracker == False:
        t.left(90)
    if tracker == False:
        t.forward(100)
    if tracker == False:
        t.right(90)
    if tracker == False:
        t.forward(100)
    if tracker == False:
        t.right(90)
    if tracker == False:
        t.forward(100)


def stop():
    global tracker
    tracker = True

def clear():
    canvas.delete("all")

root = tk.Tk()
tracker = False
canvas = tk.Canvas(width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()

t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)

tk.Button(text = "Start", command = start).pack(side = tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(text = "Stop", command = stop).pack(side = tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(text = "Clear", command = clear).pack(side = tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

This will at least stop drawing after each line but you cannot stop mid line draw.

Just for the fun of it if we add some tracking variables and use some cleaner logic we can start, stop and start again.

Update: From @cdlane's comment below I have added addition tracking and updated the clear function. This should allow for start stop start without issues and also be able to clear the field.

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk

def start(turtle_object, draw_path):
    global tracker, start_ndex, end_ndex, started
    tracker = False
    if started == False:
        started = True
        for i in range(start_ndex, end_ndex):
            if tracker == False and i <= end_ndex:
                pth = draw_path[i]
                if pth[0] == "f":
                    turtle_object.forward(pth[1])
                elif pth[0] == "r":
                    turtle_object.right(pth[1])
                elif pth[0] == "l":
                    turtle_object.left(pth[1])
                start_ndex += 1

def stop():
    global tracker, started
    tracker = True
    started = False

def clear():
    global t, tracker, started, start_ndex
    canvas.delete("all")
    tracker = False
    start_ndex = 0
    started = False
    t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)

root = tk.Tk()
tracker = False
start_ndex = 0
started = False # added this tracking variable to prevent issues with spamming the start button.

draw_path = [["f", 100], ["r", 90], ["f", 100], ["l", 90], ["f", 100], ["r", 90], ["f", 100], ["r", 90], ["f", 100]]


end_ndex = len(draw_path)

canvas = tk.Canvas(width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()

t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
tk.Button(text = "Start", command = lambda: start(t, draw_path)).pack(side = tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(text = "Stop", command = stop).pack(side = tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(text = "Clear", command = clear).pack(side = tk.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In your restartable solution, there are a couple of issues.  First, it shares the "can't recover from 'clear'" issue of the OP's original.  Second, if you're fast enough to click 'Start' multiple times during the run, the turtle goes astray.  Not nit-picking, just interested to see how you'd handle problems I ran into in my own solution.

Comment: @cdlane I agree there are limitations to my solutions. I will see if I can come up with a better solutions to contend with the other issues.

Comment: @cdlane I have updated my 2nd solution to contend with the issues you mentioned. I imaging I could probably build something cleaner but sometimes quick and dirty does the trick :D

Comment: Nice -- it runs solidly now!  The turtle library keeps an internal list of turtles that it has created, so they are effectively never garbage collected.  Better to reuse turtles, if you can, than allocate new ones.  This is with respect to your `clear()` method.

Comment: @cdlane Hum. I never used turtle before and was not aware of how it remembers each turtle. What would you do in this case?

Comment: As noted at the bottom of my answer, I'd do `t.reset()` which will remove anything this turtle has drawn, return it to its original orientation and send it back to the home position.  As if new, but not new.

Comment: I tried out this command and it works perfectly! Thank you! I will now work on the animation I want the turtle to do. Also I changed the canvas.delete(all) command to t.reset() and it works perfectly, I can start it, stop, start again and clear it and then start it again.

Comment: @Pokyzard yes changing it to `reset()` is a good idea. I was going to change it in my answer as cdlane had mentioned but I got busy. Glad you combined our answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the ideas in @Mike-SMT's answer but I'd go about it a different way.  The turtle and its controls seem very much like a Python generator to me so I've recast it as such.  The turtle moves along a path, one pixel at a time, yielding control which may, or may not return.  Or it may exhaust its path and stop the iteration:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import RawTurtle

PATH = [(100.00, 0.00), (100.00, -100.00), (200.00, -100.00), (200.00, -200.00), (100.00, -200.00)]

def run():
    for position in PATH:
        turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(position))

        while turtle.distance(position) > 1:
            turtle.forward(1)
            yield

def start():
    global generator, running

    running = True

    while running:
        try:
            next(generator)

        except ValueError:  # user clicked start but already running
            return

        except TypeError:  # new run
            turtle.reset()
            generator = run()

        except StopIteration:  # end of complete run
            generator = None
            running = False
            break

def stop():
    global running
    running = False

def clear():
    global generator
    turtle.reset()
    generator = None

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

turtle = RawTurtle(canvas, "turtle")

running = True
generator = None

tk.Button(text="Start", command=start).pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.TRUE)
tk.Button(text="Stop", command=stop).pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.TRUE)
tk.Button(text="Clear", command=clear).pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.TRUE)

root.mainloop()
```

> Also the clear button works but afterwards the start button doesn't
>   work anymore. If someone can help me with that as well.

You can replace your current `clear()` function with:

```
def clear():
    t.clear()
```

if you just want to erase the path that's been drawn but leave the turtle where it ended up.  If you want to erase the path and reset the turtle back to the starting point, instead do:

```
def clear():
    t.reset()
```

Comment: I tried this command but there were some problems with indents (the 'return') which I tried fixing by replacing    return    with    turtle.reset()    but then there were problems with 'generator' not being defined in the line    Next(generator)    .

Comment: @Pokyzard, an indentation oddity did creep in so I fixed and reloaded the example code.  I did a copy of it from this web page and paste into  a file without using an editor in between and it runs fine.  Give it another try.  (I assume you're using Python 3 based on your import of tkinter with a lower 't'.)