# Program Crashing When Using Stop Button

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm pretty new to python, but I have a working version of this in MATLAB but struggling to get the start/stop buttons to work in python.

I have tried to simplify the code I have posted below as much as I think I can, but basically I want to run a series of bleeps for a fitness test. There is a set order the beeps need to occur in order to signify different intensities of exercise.

I have used functions to write the different types of exercise (I haven't included all of that in the code below to save space), and then another to combine them into the desired protocol. Then I have created buttons to start and stop the protocol running.

The only thing I want to include that is not in the example I have put in what I have already tried is it must include a timer. The exercise sections are variable length but need to fit into a time period rather than a certain number of iterations.

I have already tried several answers on the site, the nearest one to my problem I think is;
[Previous Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326052/stop-button-in-tkinter)
The first solution here posted by Mike - SMT works on my PC, it also looks a lot like what I am trying to achieve but I have tried to match it as closely as I can but the start button still remains depressed and the stop button crashes the work.

```
# Import all modules    
import time
import winsound
import tkinter

# Define Global Variables    
runTime = 20
numberBlocks = 5
atime = 1
tracker = False

# Define Movement Functions    
def walk()    
def jog()    
def cruise()    
def sprint()    
def ar()    
def rest()

# callback functions    
def start():
    global numberBlocks, runTime, atime, tracker
    tracker = False
    t = time.time()
    i = 0
    while i < numberBlocks - 1 and tracker == False:
        while (time.time() - t) < runTime and tracker == False:
            if tracker == False and (time.time() - t) < runTime:
                walk()
            if tracker == False and (time.time() - t) < runTime:
                sprint()
            if tracker == False and (time.time() - t) < runTime:
                ar()
            if tracker == False and (time.time() - t) < runTime:
                jog()
            if tracker == False and (time.time() - t) < runTime:
                cruise()
        rest()
        i += 1

def stop():
    global tracker
    tracker = True

# run GUI    
root = tkinter.Tk()
tracker = False
root.title('LIST')

# create all of the main containers    
bottom_center_frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
bottom_center_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

# create widgets for the button frame    
button_stop = tkinter.Button(bottom_center_frame, text='Stop', command=stop).pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
button_start = tkinter.Button(bottom_center_frame, text='Start', command=start).pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

# loop gui    
root.mainloop()
```

The bleeps all work ok it just crashes when I try and stop it.

Comment: try to schedule your while loop maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the main problem here is that once you click start and launch a command in the mainloop, `tkinter` will wait until that command is over before allowing you to do something else (in this case, press stop).
A possible solution is using `.after()` like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


class FitnessApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, tracker):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.runTime = 20
        self.numberBlocks = 5
        self.atime = 1
        self.tracker = tracker

        # create all of the main containers
        self.bottom_center_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.bottom_center_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        # create widgets for the button frame
        self.button_stop = tk.Button(self.bottom_center_frame, text='Stop', command=self.stop)
        self.button_stop.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.button_start = tk.Button(self.bottom_center_frame, text='Start', command=self.start)
        self.button_start.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

    def walk(self):
        print("walking")

    def start(self):
        self.tracker = False
        self.move()

    def stop(self):
        print("Stopping run")
        self.tracker = True

    def move(self):
        if self.tracker is False:
            self.walk()
            self.after(1000, self.move)


# run GUI
tracker = False
root = FitnessApp(tracker)
root.title('LIST')

# loop gui    
root.mainloop()
```

When start is clicked, the tracker is set to False, and then the move function is called, which prints "walking".
Then the `self.after(1000, self.move)` recursively calls the move function every 1000 ms, which allows you to press the stop button, set the tracker to True and stop the simulation.

For more complicated situations, I recommend that you use the [threading module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html), which allows you to launch your simulation in a secondary thread while keeping control over the main loop. This way you can use a variable to track the progress of your simulation and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have tried to work in the self.after previously but not managed to work out how to get the complexity in there I need.

I haven't come across threading yet, but looks like that might be what I need to look into to get it to work.